# WeekDay Function is returning compile error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Whenever I seem to do anything with the WeekDay() function in Outlook-VBA, I get:

Compile Error:
Wrong number of arguments of invalid property assignment.

This occurs even in incredibly simple code such as

```
Sub WeekDayTest()

Dim intDate As Integer

intDate = WeekDay(Now())
Debug.Print intDate

End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong or is WeekDay simply not functional in Outlook's VBA environment? Everything for it seems to be centered around Excel. Interestingly, WeekDayName() seems to function correctly.

My idea for using it is in a check to return true/false if a particular date would fall under Daylight Savings Time in my time zone.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. do you have any other code in your module?

Comment: You tried `VBA.WeekDay(VBA.Now)`?

Comment: Try even intDate = WeekDay("01.01.2019")?

Comment: Check for missing references in the References dialog. Go to the VBA editor, Tools > References and see if any of the checked references are marked as "MISSING:"

Comment: If the compiler could not find the definition of `Weekday`, I would expect to see a message saying it was undefined.  Wrong number of arguments suggests it has found a non-standard definition.  (1) Is it possible you have defined a function with this name?  What happens if you write `intDate = WeekDay(Now() ,1)`?

Comment: Fresh module. Only code within is:     `Sub DSTTesting()
    Dim intDate As Integer
    intDate = WeekDay(Now(), 1)
    End Sub` No references marked missing and Tony's solution resulted in the same error. Curiously, Patrick's `VBA.WeekDay(VBA.Now)`  seems to work, returning a value of 4 for today. Could you explain a little about the different syntax and why this would work but normal WeekDay wouldn't? `VBA.WeekDay(Now)` works fine as well. As soon as the preceeding VBA is removed the error returns. Thanks for the solutions!

Answer (score 0):

PatricK's suggestion of using `VBA.WeekDay(VBA.Now)` instead of just `WeekDay()` resolved the issue.